# Servlet need to access the SQLite DB embedded in war file

Tags: java, sqlite, tomcat, servlets

I am developing a web app to run on tomcat6. I have a SQLite database created on and i want to access this SQLite db in my servlet. can some one provide me link or details to access the sqliteDB embedded in web app war file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at SQLiteJDBC project : http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/

There is an example as well :)